# 403 Forbidden error after changing permission in Linux

Tags: linux, apache, centos7

I have a Linux server running Centos 7 and Apache 2.4.6. Everything of our website is on the server.

I was going to change the permission of the sentora directory to grant access to another account. But I wasn't so familiar with it, so I accidentally input `chmod 700`. Before I changed anything, it was like this:

```
drwxrwxrwx.  9 root root   103 Apr  6 20:12 sentora
```

After I inputed "`chmod 700 sentora`" to change the permission of the directory of "sentora", it was like this:

```
drwx------.  9 root root   103 Apr  6 20:12 sentora
```

and then my website has gone down, and it shows:

```
 You don't have permission to access / on this server.
 Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
```

So I tried to revert everything back. Trying `chmod 755`, `775`, `777`. 
And now everything looks the same as before.

But the error is still there. This is an online platform for my students. They go online to do quizzes all the time.

Comment: What is your http server? Try restarting it. Try also restarting web browser and refresh with caching disabled (something like Ctrl-F5, Shift-F5). Did you change ownership or permissions recursively (-R option of chmod/chown)? What is the http server config (document root, errordocument)? What does it says in its error.log log file about access?

Comment: apache. I rebooted the server every time I made changes and It's still not working. The website doesn't work on another browser as well.
I created a new group called 'coder" and added an account to that group, I thought it was the problem so now I deleted it. and it's showing: RL:x:1000:RL. 
Where can I find the error.log log file?

Comment: so now I saw our website folder is this:
drwxrwxrwx 12 RL apache 215 Apr  8 14:38 "my website link"
RL is the account that I changed the ownership of the sentora directory to.
I'm pretty sure before anything happened, the directory wasn't owned by RL but root.
But then it wouldn't make sense because it it was set to root, it wouldn't have been able to have my students access to the website, am I correct?

Comment: To find error.log use https://serverfault.com/questions/189205 (probably somewhere in /var/log or /var/log/httpd/). Your website files are accessed by http server (apache probably), and it is started from root user or from special 'apache' user and group, not from your students user id. And apache does it own permissions checks (in http protocol there is no user id field, and server will not trust such field. Access is regulated by apache config and/or `.htaccess` files in directories if enabled).

Comment: I can't figure the error_log file. Can anyone help me to see if there's anything wrong? Thanks!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/49spb037mwqmbt1/Screen%20Shot%202017-05-28%20at%2023.53.01.png?dl=0

Comment: There are not errors about file access in this error_log. Try to access the url with browser several times and search for new lines in error_log (and in access_log), then post `tail -n 30` of both files as text, not as image.

Comment: The error_log isn't showing anything after 00:49, even though I've hit the website many times after that. 
I just contacted my hosing provided FatCow and they said it was because I've got my subdomain pointing to a url that's provided by noip.com (e.g. xxxxxx.ddns.net). And there was an empty folder with the exact name as the ddns.net, (e.g.xxxxxx.ddns.net) folder in File Manager so the domain was pointing to that folder instead of pointing to URL. Now they have removed the folder and it should work, according to FatCow, is it true?

Comment: Don't know about your internet setup. Check access_log too, and check page access locally on your server (if you has ssh access - with some cli like `wget` or curl or text browser like `lynx` or `links`).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: not sure if this helps, but on debian apache htdocs must be owned by www-data:www-data

Comment: thank you – osgx for the suggestion about " cli like wget or curl or text browser like lynx or links". Later I found out some files weren't changed to 775 permission. Thanks a lot!